# How can I store a value in an 'if' statement to use later in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm wondering how I can store some value in an `IF()` statement so that Excel isn't having to do some calculation twice.  Is there a way to store something into a variable?

So example, let's say I have something like this:

```
=IF(ISNA(CalculateSomething(cellref)),"something",CalculateSomething(cellref))
```

It seems like a waste to have `CalculateSomething(cellref)` run twice here, especially on a large spreadsheet.

Is there a way to store the return from `CalculateSomething(cellref)` somewhere to use in the `else` part of the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `IFERROR()` instead:

```
=IFERROR(CalculateSomething(cellref),"something")
```

There's no way AFAIK to store a step calculation unless you're using a helper column.